# Are constant numbers (rank-0 tensors that are fixed) considered as symmetric tensors?

Tags: tensors

So there are some interesting symmetric rank 0 tensors, for example the Kronecker delta .....  But my question is more simple than that..... Is a number like 1 , 5, e , etc considered symmetric? I would say yes, but I was recently told no in my physics class

Comment: I would also say yes.

Comment: The Kronecker delta is a rank 2 tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scalars do not have the property of symmetry. However, a 1 dimensional 2nd rank tensor, or equivalently, it's representation as a 1x1 matrix $[x]$ is symmetric.

A complex 1x1 matrix $[x]$ where x is real is Hermitian.
A complex 1x1 matrix $[x]$ where x is pure imaginary is antihermitian.